# Add validation summary

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

How can I add validation to tensorboard? I have written a wrappers for layers, like:

```
def convolution(input_data, kernel_shape, strides, activation, name=None):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        kernel = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(kernel_shape, stddev=stddev), name="weights")
        bias = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([kernel_shape[-1]]), name="biases")

        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input=input_data, filter=kernel, strides=strides, padding="SAME", name="convolutions")
        result = activation(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, bias), name="activations")

    tf.scalar_summary(name + "/mean", tf.reduce_mean(kernel))    
    return result
```

and use `summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()` in `main`. Also I have implemented `train_op` and `valid_op`, which both calls `inference` function. However, there appears an error that we have duplicate tags for scalar_summary, i.e. `inference` is used in both `train_op` and `valid_op`, which lead to duplication of, say, `conv1/mean` summary.

How can I make this work? I need is to run train and validation using the same function `inference`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error suggests, you cannot have two summaries with the same tag. This happens in your case because you are calling `tf.scalar_summary` twice with the same tag, once when constructing the `train_op` and once when constructing the `valid_op`. Here is a possible solution :
You can add a flag to your `inference` function, say `is_training`, to indicate that the code is being called to construct part of a training graph. You would have to thread that flag to all your layer functions. In `convolution` for instance, you should do the following :

```
if is_training:
  tf.scalar_summary(name + "/mean", tf.reduce_mean(kernel))
return result
```

When constructing the `train_op`, you pass `is_training=True`, and when constructing the `valid_op`, you pass `is_training=False`. There is an example of such a programming pattern [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_model.py#L48) in the Inception model.

Comment: So the solution is just to avoid summaries explicitly while validating. I was considering this approach but was hoping there is a smarter one. Anyway, thanks for help!

Comment: Another question is: using this approach the TEST summary will be added to TRAIN summary. I can encapsulate test summary by "test/" tag and use a separate summary_writer. But is there a smart approach to manage summaries?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use different name scopes for summaries and then filter them by merge_summary's scope argument, instead of merge_all_summaries.